# Does grep distinguish a variable and the $ regex?

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I want to grep for a variable that has the string `test`, but I also want to make sure that it will only find `test` if that is the only word on a line.

So, I tried this:

```
string=test
echo "test" | grep "$string$"
```

I would like to know if `grep` knows that the first part, `$string` (in grep "**$string**$"), is asking to find for the string `test`, while the last part, `$` (in grep "$string **$**" is asking to find for `test`, but nothing should be after `test` in the line. Is `grep` able to distinguish `$string` as a variable and only `$` as the regex for end of the line, or do I have to use a certain way to distinguish them apart?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Grep knows nothing it does not see. If grep sees `$string$`, it will try to match `$string{end-of-line}`. What happens is that the shell expands the variable `$string` before `grep` kicks in, so that `grep` receives
`test$` as the regex.

But, given the word `$string$`, why is the last `$` is not expanded while
`$string` is?  Because `$` is not a valid variable name. This is very clear
in the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09):

> If the parameter is not enclosed in braces, and is a name,
> **the expansion shall use the longest valid name** (see [XBD Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235)),
> whether or not the variable represented by that name exists.

And [XBD name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) states

> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores,
> digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set.
> The first character of a name is not a digit.

And there are also [special parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), such as `$$`, `$@`, `$#`, etc..

If you don't want to remember all this, simply follow [Gordon Davisson's advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277993/does-grep-distinguish-a-variable-and-the-regex/1278006#comment2167429_1278006)
and escape every `$` that should not introduce a variable to ensure it will
be preserved.

```
$ echo "$string$"
test$
$ echo "$string\$"
test$
$ echo "\$string\$"
$string$
```

Also remember variables are expanded in double-quotes but not in single quotes.

```
$ echo 'test' | grep '$string$'   # No match, $string is not expanded    
$ echo 'test' | grep "$string$"   # Match, $string is expanded
test
```

> I want to grep for a variable that has the string `test`, but I also want to make sure that it will only find `test` if that is the only word on a line.

For that, you need either the regex `^test$` (to anchor the string both to the start and end of line) or to use the [`-x` flag of `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Matching-Control.html#Matching-Control). Your original attempt would match `Atest` because the regex `test$` is not anchored to the start of line.

```
$ echo Atest | grep "$string$"
Atest
$ echo Atest | grep -x "$string"
$ echo Atest | grep "^$string$"
```

Comment: Using `"$string$"` in the shell seems like bad practice to me; I'd escape the final `$` (as in `"$string\$"`) instead. Normally, when `$` occurs in a double-quoted section of a shell command, it's initiating a variable substitution (`$test`), command substitution, etc. But when it's followed by a double-quote, that doesn't make sense, so the shell just passes it through literally. That's what you want here, but it seems like kind of an accident that it works, and (as indicated by the original question) it's not obvious. Escaping is the normal way to include a literal `$`, so I'd use that.

Comment: Note that in the fish shell and (t)csh, the second dollar sign in `echo "$string$"` is an error.

Comment: @ilkkachu: But csh quoting rules are arcane; (t)csh doesn’t accept ```"$string\$"``` (what Gordon suggested) either.  It seems that all shells (I tested ash, bash, dash, fish, tcsh and zsh) accept ```"$string"\$``` (with the ```\$``` ***outside*** the quotes) or ```"$string"'$'```.